# How to get two sums from two tables in one output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- `Receive_Amount_Details` for crediting amount from the construction site owner, and
- `SitewiseEmployee` for debiting the amount to pay the laborer.

For every single `Date`, which is present in both tables, I want to:

- sum all of the `Amount_Received` from `Receive_Amount_Details` as `Total_Receive_Amount_from_siteowner`, and
- sum all of the `Amount` from `SitewiseEmployee` as `Total_Amount_Payed_to_Labour`
  column on output table.

Both tables have the `Date` column, but I want a single `Date` column in the output.

If any single day amount is not received and labour was paid, it should be in the output table, and also if any single day amount was received but not paid for labour, then also it needs to be present in the output table.

```
CREATE TABLE `Receive_Amount_Details` (
    `Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `SiteId` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `Amount_Received` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `Date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    KEY `SiteId` (`SiteId`),
    CONSTRAINT `Receive_Amount_Details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SiteId`) 
        REFERENCES `SiteList` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `SitewiseEmployee` (
    `Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `SiteId` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `EmployeeId` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `Amount` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    KEY `SiteId` (`SiteId`),
    KEY `EmployeeId` (`EmployeeId`),
    CONSTRAINT `SitewiseEmployee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SiteId`) 
        REFERENCES `SiteList` (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `SitewiseEmployee_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeId`)
        REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you may have dates in the one table that are not present in the other, and vice versa, you would need to perform a full outer join. MySql does not have such a join type, but you can achieve it with a union:

```
select    `Date`,
          sum(Amount_Received) as Sum_Amount_Received,
          sum(Amount) as Sum_Amount
from      (
                select `Date`, Amount_Received, 0 as Amount
                from   Receive_Amount_Details
                union
                select `Date`, 0, Amount
                from   SitewiseEmployee
          ) as dates
group by  `Date`;
```

Comment: Thanks, But When Date matches for both table, Amount gets doubled

Comment: Genius :) :)  Thanks a lot